# What is the reason for a line height of 1.33333 on Bootstrap btn-lg?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

The bootstrap `.btn` class has the following styles:

```
display: inline-block;
padding: 6px 12px;
margin-bottom: 0px;
font-size: 14px;
font-weight: normal;
line-height: 1.42857;
text-align: center;
white-space: nowrap;
vertical-align: middle;
cursor: pointer;
-moz-user-select: none;
background-image: none;
border: 1px solid transparent;
border-radius: 4px;
```

When I use `btn-lg` a class to increase the button size, the following styles are applied:

```
.btn-lg, .btn-group-lg > .btn {
    padding: 10px 16px;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 1.33333;
    border-radius: 6px;
}
```

Of course `.btn-lg` overrides a few properties of `.btn` most noticeably, the `padding` and the `line-height`. Adding padding makes the button look bigger obviously. But here is what interests me: the line height. Why is the `line-height` reduced to  `1.33333`. I take keen interest in website layouts and so I ask this question. Obviously your answer could be "it's a design decision".

But I don't just think they put that number there randomly. I think it's some careful math, so could just somebody demystify this for me? I mean what math lead to the Bootstrap developers to add a line height of `line-height: 1.33333;` to `btn-lg` and that would be my only question.

Comment: afaik its `em` and so 130% of its text, couldnt tell you why they chose it though, guess the counter question is why not ? :)

Comment: the number value of line-height is relevant to the font size, it makes sense that reducing the number on a bigger font, however don't know why 1.33333, normally .xx would be good enough, i.e. 1.33 maybe it's just the developers' personal styles.

Comment: @Pangloss haha , you second comment makes sense ! Thanks ! i'll try asking the same question on git maybe :)

Answer (score 5):

The `1.33333` value with 5 decimals is needed to fix the [#15497 Bootstrap issue](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/15497) which happened on Win 8.1 with Chrome. It appears that `1.33` was just not precise enough to represent `4/3`.

In this way, `1.33` has been changed in multiple files: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/commit/4ed95f5fa298d861c5fa53ae2a3a0dcb4901bd69

---

The *reason* why 1.33 is enough in most cases but not with Win 8.1/Chrome is explained by [patrickhlauke](https://github.com/patrickhlauke):

> it seems the culprit may be the line height of 23.94xxx leading to
>   some rounding issue in chrome. left button is 24px tall, while right
>   one only 23px for some reason...

Comment: Superb , thanks ! , the question still remains , Why just 1.3333 ?

Comment: if you increase the line height any more it might push content down further than expected. It is likely the larger size of the button is only meant to increase the look not the spacing around it?